# is $f(x)=[x]+(x-[x])^{[x]}$ uniform continuous on $(0,+ \infty )$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Is $f(x)=[x]+(x-[x])^{[x]}$ uniform continuous on $(0,+ \infty )$ ?

It is clear that $\lim_{x \to +\infty } f(x) $ does not exist. Is this an alternative function ?

Comment: How do you define $[x]$?

Comment: [x] is the largest integer less than or equal to x .

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
x\in(0,0.5)\Rightarrow
f(x)
&=0+(x-0)^0
\\
&=1
\\
x\in(0.5,1)\Rightarrow
f(x)
&=1+(x-1)^1
\\
&=x
\end{align}$$

So $f(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=0.5$ since it approaches $1$ from the left and $0.5$ from the right, which implies that $f$ is also not uniformly continuous.

Comment: [x]=0 if 0<x<1 but in your answer for .5<x<1 [x]=1. I define [x] in above.

Comment: @amirbahadory I see. Normally you would define $[x]$ as the closest integer to $x$, and notate your function as $\lfloor x \rfloor$. It'd probably be easier to define your function in the question next time :)